# Firebase makes Tasks execute only on main thread causing Unity to freeze

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, firebase, task

I have an issue with *firebase 1.1.0* for `Unity SDK`.

As soon as I activate firebase by `FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl( myurl )` all **Tasks** not generated by *firebase* are executed on the main thread. 
So I can retrieve and post data to *firebase* just fine and even process it in tasks.  They run on separate thread, which I see when debugging. However when I will use `Task.Run( MyComputingFunction )` in the `Start` method of some MonoBehaviour the *Unity* hangs. Assume that this function just counts from `0` to `999999` so it is not a *locking* problem. For the time of calculation *Unity* freezes because the task is executed on the main thread. If I will comment out *firebase* activation my *task* will run in separate *thread* and will not freeze *Unity*.

Please help.

Here is a minimal working example. Attach it to a game object and observe tasks running parallel. Uncomment pointed line and tasks will execute in linear order.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
using Firebase.Database;

public class NetworkController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static DatabaseReference @ref;

    void Start()
    {
        // Uncomment line below
        //InitializeDatabase();
        TestStuff();
    }

    private void TestStuff()
    {
        Task.Run( Counter(1) );
        Task.Run( Counter(2) );
        Task.Run( Counter(3) );
    }

    private Action Counter( int i )
    {
        return delegate {
            int a = 0;
            while ( a + 10 < 900000 ) {
                a++;
                if ( a % 5000 == 0 )
                    Debug.Log( a + i);
            }
        };
    }

    private void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl( "https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/" );

        @ref = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox I've updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a firebase engineer and have just looked at your post.  I'm sorry you hit this.

This is a bug in the UnityTask library that we rely on.  What's happening is that the task library is mis-using SynchronizationContext.Current (when set) as a vehicle to launch tasks.  Task.Run should always use the threadpool and not ever SynchronizationContext.Current.  SynchronizationContext.Current is meant to be used to marshal calls from other threads.

I will investigate fixing this on our side.  I do have a workaround for you to use in the meantime.

```
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(new TaskScheduler(null)); //null = threadpool.
factory.StartNew(() => myFunction());
```

Comment: The PR for this fix is [here:](https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FParsePlatform%2FParse-SDK-dotNET%2Fpull%2F251)
Until this fix is approved, you'll need to use the workaround.

Comment: No problem. Thank You very much for the workaround. Firebase is awesome and I'm glad You integrate it into Unity.

Comment: Still not fixed yet?

Comment: @BenjaminWulfe Problem now is calling firebase from TaskFactory with  TaskScheduler(null) work. But then we can't call unity function inside that task function. Because unity function must be called from unity's own thread

Comment: That isnt a firebase issue.  That's a question about how to use the task library from microsoft.  If you need execution to run on a certain thread, you should be using a specific taskscheduler.

Comment: So in your case you'd do something like:
var uitaskscheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;
...
Task UITask= bkgtask.ContinueWith(() =>
    {
     this.TextBlock1.Text = "Complete"; 
    }, uitaskscheduler);
So to be clear, firebase now conforms to the design of the task library on other platforms.  If you were previously relying on incorrect task behavior to run tasks on the ui thread, the above change should help you address it.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm an engineer from the firebase C++ / Unity team.)

I believe we fixed this in a past release.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.0.3

Recently we just released 4.3.0 and since this was reported several more improvements and fixes have been made with threading and Tasks.